# Android SQLite Where Clause NPE

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Query:

```
public List<Pontos> selectSpecific(String id) {
   List<Pontos> list = new ArrayList<Pontos>();
   Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "id", "name" },
           "id"+" = ?", new String[] { id }, null, null, null);
   if (cursor == null) {
          return list;
      }
   if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
           Pontos p = new Pontos();
           p.id = cursor.getLong(0);
           p.name = cursor.getString(1);
           list.add(p); 
       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
     cursor.close();
  }
   return list;
```

}

Fetching the result:

```
public class Showplace extends Activity {

   private String id;
   DataHelper dh = new DataHelper(Showplace.this);
   TextView txtTitle = null;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.showplace);

       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       id = Integer.toString(extras.getInt("id"));
       txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
       List<Pontos> list = this.dh.selectSpecific(id);
       for(Pontos p : list){
           txtTitle.setText(p.getName().toString());
       }
   }
```

}

It's giving me an NPE, I think that's in this line:

```
Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "id", "name" },
       "id"+" = ?", new String[] { id }, null, null, null);
```

I tried various ways of doing this, searched a lot over StackOverflow and I can't seem to find a solution to this.

**Edit:**

LogCat:

> 

```
03-02 10:22:09.244: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dotpro.android.bikevento/com.dotpro.android.bikevento.Showplace}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:193)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.dotpro.android.bikevento.DataHelper.<init>(DataHelper.java:28)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.dotpro.android.bikevento.Showplace.<init>(Showplace.java:14)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
03-02 10:22:09.304: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: You can check in your logcat exactly what's the line that's throwing your NPE. If it's really that line, you should output the value of the string id to check it doesn't contain a null value. 
Also, I think you should have a "_id" field instead of a "id" field. But if that was the problem it would throw an IllegalArgumentException instead.

Comment: I added complete LogCat!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this line is wrong:
`DataHelper dh = new DataHelper(Showplace.this);`

you should move `dh = new DataHelper(Showplace.this);` to onCreate method

### Edit:

why?
because if you initialize field dh as you do Activity is not fully created and the context is not valid